# I'm trying to show specific user details through bs4 collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

Displaying the all user record using foreach loop

> View

```
<div class="row tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
    <div class="col-md-12 tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-donner" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-donner-tab">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
                <div class="media pb-3">
                    <img class="mr-3 border rounded-circle" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(item.DP)" width="100" height="100">
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <div class="row member">
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <h3>
                                    <a asp-action="Profile" asp-controller="Accounts" asp-route-id="@item.Id">@item.userName</a>

                                    <small>
                                        @if (item.crId == 1)
                                        {
                                            <span>Donner</span>
                                        }
                                    </small>
                                </h3>
                                <span>
                                    <i class="fal fa-clock"></i> @item.Created.ToString("yyyy")
                                </span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-6 pl-5 pt-3">
                                <a class="float-right" data-toggle="collapse"  href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                                    <i class="fas fa-angle-double-down"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
                                    <div class="card card-body">
                                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>                           
                    </div>
                </div>
           }
    </div>
```

> Result
>   [image]

When click on down arrow icon link above image the all users detail are open but I want to show only that particular user detail collapse how to do this? and i also try that user @item.Id into collapse link and div but not work.

Comment: Your elements appear to be repeating the element ID property for each record you display in the loop. You need to find a way to make the IDs unique for the collapse to work properly. Look at the Accordion example to see how to have only one record "open" at a time -> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `@item.Id` to specific a unique Id for each collapse block in the loop code.

```
@{ 
   var UnqiueId = "collapseExample" + item.Id;
}

<div class="col-6 pl-5 pt-3">
<a class="float-right" data-toggle="collapse" href="#@UnqiueId" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="@UnqiueId">
    <i class="fas fa-angle-double-down"></i>
</a>
</div>
<div class="col-12">
<div class="collapse" id="@UnqiueId">
    <div class="card card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```